# Iterate through a dask series (getting unique values from dask series to list)

Tags: python, dask

I need to iterate through unique values from a dask dataframe. I used .unique() to get the unique values of the columns but now i'm given a dask object that I cannot use to iterate. I need to know how to get these unique values out of this dask object into a list (or something similar) so I can use those values to iterate through the dask dataframe.

```
df = dd.read_csv('file.csv')
df.column1.unique()
for unique_value in column1_array:
    print(unique_value)
```

This is the error I get:
NotImplementedError: Series getitem in only supported for other series objects with matching partition structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in dask=2.3.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: import dask.dataframe as dd
   ...: import dask

In [2]: dask.__version__
Out[2]: '2.3.0'

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({"temp1":[1,2,2,4],"temp2":[1,2,2,4]})
   ...: ddf = dd.from_pandas(df,npartitions=2)
   ...: for unique_value in ddf.temp1.unique():
   ...:     print(unique_value)
   ...:     
1
2
4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.compute()` method to convert your Dask Series into a Pandas Series object and then iterate over that.

```
for x in s.compute():
    ...
```

See https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html#reduce-and-then-use-pandas

There are also  `iteritems` and `iterrows` methods